# Basic Java Swing, how to exit and dispose of your application/JFrame

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

What is a good way to dispose of a JFrame with code like this?  I want to handle the Window exit and window close.

I know we shouldn't use System.exit();

```
public class JavaCellularAutomataSquare {

  public static final String TITLE = "Cellular Automata - Squaring Example";

  private int maxWidth = 600;
  private int maxHeight = 600;

  public void launch() {    
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);   
    frame.setLocation(20, 20);    
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(maxWidth, maxHeight));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setFocusable(true);

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLocation(20, 20);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(maxWidth, maxHeight));    
    panel.setFocusable(true);
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);

    // Panel setup, toggle visibility on frame
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);    
  }

}
```

Comment: Please check out Andrew's answer here: [awt-window-close-listener-event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073412/awt-window-close-listener-event/7073630#7073630)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to quit a java app from within the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670956/how-to-quit-a-java-app-from-within-the-program)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ClosingFrame extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar MenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JMenu File = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    public ClosingFrame() {
        File.add(Exit);
        MenuBar.add(File);
        Exit.addActionListener(new ExitListener());
        WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                        "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                        "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
                if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        };
        frame.addWindowListener(exitListener);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar(MenuBar);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ExitListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                    "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ClosingFrame cf = new ClosingFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the standard (good way) to handle on close events.  Looks good.

Comment: @Berlin Brown I hope that yes, works for me as I expected, but in Swing not possible declare two or more http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html with setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);, because each of them kill JVM instance, you have to accepted that or to set another with HIDE or DISPOSE :-)

Comment: I like this.  I asked a kind of generic question but this was the response I was looking for.  Also, the others were good but this had the code.

Answer (score 8):

`JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` frees up resources when the window is closed. You can see some of the other operations in the Java tutorials [here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

The possible arguments that you can use in the method are defined in the [WindowConstants](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html) interface, if you are curious about your options.

Comment: How is that different than EXIT_ON_CLOSE

Comment: @Berlin, `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` terminates the application, whereas `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` only disposes of the `JFrame` instance.

Comment: DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE will let the AWT thread exit when there are no non-disposed AWT components.  That will be your last thread so the main thread will exit.

Comment: Exactly. @Berlin, Take a look at that link to the Java tutorials; it enumerates the differences.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to perform some operations while closing your application, propably you need a 
[shut down hook](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29). Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/java-useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook).

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

[JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(int operation)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29)

[JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

Comment: This actually uses `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Is there an event handler for frame.setDefaultCloseOperation?  E.g.  is there a method I can override?  onExit() { }  or something similar.

Comment: @Berlin: Once you set the default close operation, there is no need to override a method. Unless you implement a window listener to do something different, the default close operation is performed when the user closes the window.

Comment: But if I wanted to, I can use window listener.

Comment: @Berlin: Yup, you can do something else with the window listener if you want to.