# Closing a java program properly when JDialog is the main window

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

I have a JDialog as the main window in my application (originally it was a JFrame but it showed in the taskbar which I didn't want).

Currently I am doing:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

and when I click an exit button:

```
frame.dispose();
```

But the process still seems to hang around in the background

JFrame had `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` which seemed to do what I wanted.

How can I close my application properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add

```
  System.exit(0);
```

where you want the program to end, maybe immediately after the dispose() line.

Comment: I thought that shut down the entire JVM.  Will it only close for the current application?

Answer (score 20):

You need to add a WindowListener that will do System.exit(0) when the dialog closes.

```
JDialog dialog = ...;
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { 
    @Override public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { 
      System.exit(0);
    }
  });
```

Of course, the System.exit(0) after you hit the Exit button (that was suggested elsewhere in this thread) is still needed.

Comment: This is it. In my case, we have ` JPanel ` extended wiith ` JDialog ` so I was not able to call ` addWindowListerner ` directly. But since we extended our dialog with `JDialog `, I was able to call ` super.addWindowListener... ` and it works.

Answer (score 3):

consider using `JWindow`(un-decoretad by defalut), but that's little bit complicating fact, that `JWindow` required initializations from `JFrame` (just must exist, nothing else) as parent

better would be add `WindowListener` and all Events/Actions would be redirected/managed [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080638/basic-java-swing-how-to-exit-and-dispose-of-your-application-jframe/7082054#7082054)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You know that the [`EXIT_ON_CLOSE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE) field is also inherited by `JDialog`, right?</strike>

As mentioned by [@camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr), `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is not a valid value for the [`setDefaultCloseOperation`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) method of the `JDialog` class. As stated by the API,

> Sets the operation that will happen by default when the user initiates
>   a "close" on this dialog. You must specify one of the following
>   choices:
>
> - `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` (defined in `WindowConstants`): Don't do anything; require the program to handle the operation in the
>     windowClosing method of a registered WindowListener object.
> - `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` (defined in `WindowConstants`): Automatically hide the dialog after invoking any registered `WindowListener` objects.
> - `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide and dispose the dialog after invoking any registered `WindowListener` objects.

If `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is passed as an argument, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.

Comment: Yeah it does, I was using WindowBuilder for creating the GUI and it was not an available option so I thought it was not available.  Thanks

Comment: -1, Really? In JDK6, according to the API EXIT_ON_CLOSE is not valid and when I try using it I get an IllegalArgumentException at runtime. If this is a new feature in JDK7 I'll remove the down vote after a comment is added indicating the new functionality.

Comment: @mre not easy to do that programatically, all of Top-Level Containers has something **** call it wrong, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540354/java-swing-the-right-action-to-take-upon-closing-windows , maybe for refreshing another issue(s) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime

Comment: @camickr, Hmm..you're right. I still cannot find where this is written in the API though. I'm not sure that the down-vote was warranted, but that's the kind of person you are. So, whatever. If you could point me to the specific lines that state this field is not valid, I'd be more than appreciative. But this does not make my answer untrue. The API clearly shows that `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is an inherited field. Not my fault this particular subtlety is poorly documented AFAIK.

Comment: @mre, so its ok to upvote wrong answers, but its not ok to downvote wrong answers? What is the point of downvoting? This answer is wrong and misleading, that is why I down voted it! The valid values are clearly documented in the API for the `setDefaultCloseOperation()` method. I still can't believe this got an upvote AFTER my comment was made. By the way no where in my answer did I attack your character, I simply stated the answer was wrong. We all make mistakes (I know I do all the time), I just hope we learn from them.

Comment: @camickr, Not sure who upvoted, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. And for others, see [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

For me worked only with windowClosing event:

```
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                     System.exit(0);
                }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below amazing source code -

```
JDialog dialog = (JDialog) container;
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setModal(false);
dialog.setVisible(false);
dialog.dispose();

Runtime.getRuntime().exit(1);
```

this above said will shut off the process as well as after disposing the JDialog container, also one more benefit is there, if this JDialog is running above any other JFrame or JDialog, so the parent will not terminate but if this JDialog is running on its own, then the process will get terminated completely, Enjoy.