# Infinite while loop? - Terminate button appears

Tags: java, eclipse, button, terminate

After closing the GUI, my program is still running. I need to use "terminate" red button in eclipse. What's happening?

There are only two classes

main class:

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;



public class zTestCombo2 extends JDialog // implements ActionListener
{

    private JList<String> leftlist;

    public zTestCombo2 (JFrame owner) // creates layout
    {
    setSize(1250,800);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);

    zReader2.getValue();
    leftlist = new JList<String>(zReader2.apps());  
    add(new JScrollPane(leftlist));
    leftlist.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);  
    JScrollPane scrollList = new JScrollPane(leftlist);
    scrollList.setBounds(50,250,150,300);
    add(scrollList);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        zTestCombo2 two = new zTestCombo2(null);
    }}
```

and the Reader, which main class uses. I used "reader.close()" so i don't get whats wrong

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class zReader2{        
    static ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String[] lineArray ;

static int rowsnumber;

    public static void getValue()
    {  
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt/zapp.txt"));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                lines.add(line);
                rowsnumber++;
            }
            reader.close();
            lineArray = new String[rowsnumber];     
            lines.toArray(lineArray);   

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static String getRow(int row){   
        return lines.get(row-1);
    }
    public static int getRowsNumber(){  
        return rowsnumber;
    }
    public static String[] apps(){
        return lineArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am getting it right, your question looks almost identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191330/closing-a-java-program-properly-when-jdialog-is-the-main-window I would do it using the answer given by Itay Maman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell your JDialog what it should do when you close it, otherwise it will just hide and the program keeps running. Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29).

```
JDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```