# Exiting an application using "setDefaultCloseOperation" with a dialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, setdefault

I have code with the class `MainFrame`, and the `this` is a mainframe object. So here's my problem. When I do `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`, it closes out of the dialog, but not the application. I know I should be using `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, but that only works for a `JFrame`, and not a `MainFrame` object. I've tried work arounds using `System.exit(0)`, but they all either exit at the wrong time, or fail all together. Is there anyway in which I can access the "X" button in the corner of the frame, and set it so that when it is pressed, it performs a certain action?

Comment: Show some code. How does your `MainFrame` class look like?

Comment: In case you extend a `JDialog`: Try `JDialog.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: *....access the "X" button in the corner of the frame* YES, [`JFrame#addWindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html), see [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191330/closing-a-java-program-properly-when-jdialog-is-the-main-window) link also

Comment: *"I know I should be using EXIT_ON_CLOSE, but that only works for a JFrame"* - What proof have you got for this?  Have you tested it?

Comment: Ummm...yes I have actually MadProgrammer. It's actually a direct call only from the JFrame API.

Answer (score 0):

Azad's comment worked! Go to the link as described.

EDIT: Better yet, lemme post the correct idea here in case that question ever disappears.

```
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { 
@Override public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { 
  System.exit(0);
  }
});
```

Where dialog is your JDialog with all the info. I recommend posting it at the end of your method where your JDialog is defined and used.

Comment: Why don't you just write `dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`?

Comment: JDialog has to be a "DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE". Only a JFrame can do a EXIT_ON_CLOSE.

Answer (score 0):

> it closes out of the dialog, but not the application.

Why are you trying to exit an application from a dialog? An application should only close through its JFrame.

> Is there anyway in which I can access the "X" button in the corner of the frame, and set it so that when it is pressed, it performs a certain action?

See [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for ideas on the subject as well as code examples.

Comment: Because when I tried throwing it into a JFrame, I was getting crazy, poorly-formatted GUIs that were perfect in a JDialog.

Comment: @user3010468, The layout in a JFrame or JDialog is identical. Your code is the problem, not the JFrame. That is why you always create a GUI by adding components to a panel and then add the panel to the frame. I suggest you fix your code.