# How can I exit only my sub-program, not the whole VM?

Tags: java, exit, system.exit

I have a Java swing launcher program to launch another class (running its main method).
Each program has its cancel button to exit itself.

I use `System.exit(0);` when this cancel button is pressed.

The launcher program does this in `actionPerformed`:

```
if (source==carMenuItem) {
    ta.append("Car launched\n");
    TestCar.main(par);

}
if (source==DialogboxMenuItem) {
    ta.append("Dialogbox launched\n");            
    DialogBox.main(par);
}        
if (source==LengthConversionMenuItem) {
    ta.append("LengthConversion launched\n");            
    LengthConversion.main(par);           
}
```

When I press the program's cancel button, it also closes my launcher program. How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: See my answer to [Preventing System.exit() from API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401281/preventing-system-exit-from-api/5401319#5401319).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System.exit()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)  terminates the VM therefore your initial thread is terminated also, simply return from your main() method.

After reviewing you code: Not all classes are supposed to have a main() method (If not also used standalone). You should consider to call a constructor to create an instance of a class and call a method not named main().

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `dispose()` method in stead of `System.exit()` :-because `System.exit()` will terminate the total application it self.

or you can use `setVisible()` as false.

Answer (score 2):

you have to implements [WindowListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) and its `WindowEvents`, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080638/basic-java-swing-how-to-exit-and-dispose-of-your-application-jframe/7082054#7082054)

another option is [setDefaultCloseOperation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) properly

Answer (score 1):

With System.exit you can't. This will terminate the whole JVM and all processes inside it.