# Java Release Resources

Tags: java, memory, jtable, derby

I'm having a problem with a code. In MainFrame.java I'm creating a new JDialog which loads a ResultSet from a derby database to a jTable. I've inserted 150000 rows in the database for testing purpose. Loading the values from ResultSet into jTable (in LoadTable() method), increases java.exe system resource memory about 500 mb.
The problem is when disposing the JDialog, the 500 mb used are not freed up. They are freed up only when calling system.exit() in MainFrame.java.

When I reopen the JDialog, the memoryresources increase up to 800mb. The 3rd reopen of the JDialog increase the memory up to 1 Gb, and so on.

Here are the codes used:
1) Calling JDialog:

```
   private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                           
    {                                               
        try
        {
            Database.GetConnection().commit();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            Log.GetLogger().log(Level.ALL, "jMenuItem1ActionPerformed() Method in MainFrame.Java, Database error!", ex);
            MessageBox.ShowMessage(this, ex.toString(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        Insert ins = new Insert(this, true);
        ins.setVisible(true);
    }
```

2) Loading values into jTable:

```
    private void LoadTable() throws SQLException
    {

        Timestamp tstart = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

        //get all from database
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = Database.GetCutiiAll();

        Timestamp tstop1 = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

        //create a model for the table
        int len = Database.GetColoaneArr().length + 1;
        javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, len);
        //set table headers for columns
        String[] headers = new String[Database.GetColoaneArr().length + 1];
        headers[0] = "ID";
        System.arraycopy(Database.GetColoaneArr(), 0, headers, 1, headers.length - 1);
        tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(headers);
        //set selection mode
        table1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //insert rows to table
        int rowNo = 0;
        while (rs.next())
        {
            //create object array with values for table columns
            int length = headers.length;
            Object[] data = new Object[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                //parse values where are foreign keys in the database
                Object val = rs.getObject(headers[i]);
                switch (headers[i])
                {
                    case "SERIE":
                    {
                        String[] temp = Database.GetSerii();
                        int index = (int) val;

                        data[i] = temp[index - 1];
                        break;
                    }
                    case "PROTECTIE_EX_1":
                    case "PROTECTIE_EX_2":
                    case "PROTECTIE_EX_3":
                    {
                        String[] temp = Database.GetProtectii();
                        int index = (int) val;

                        data[i] = temp[index - 1];
                        break;
                    }
                    case "TIP_MATERIAL":
                    {
                        String[] temp = Database.GetMateriale();
                        int index = (int) val;

                        data[i] = temp[index -1];
                        break;
                    }
                    default: 
                    {
                        data[i] = rs.getObject(headers[i]);
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            }
            tableModel.insertRow(rowNo, data);
            rowNo++;
        }
        //attach model to table
        table1.setModel(tableModel);
        //create listeners to update database when changing values        
        Timestamp tstop2 = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        //show how long it took to load the database
        long s = tstop2.getTime() - tstart.getTime();
        jDurata.setText(String.valueOf(s) + " ms");
    }
```

3) Disposing JDialog:

```
private void jBtnIesireActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (Database.GetCanSave())
    {
        int answer = MessageBox.ShowConfirmationMessage(this, "Salvati modificarile inainte de a iesi?", "OPTIUNE", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        switch (answer)
        {
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION: break;
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION: {
                try 
                {
                    Database.Save();
                }
                catch (SQLException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(Insert.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    Log.GetLogger().log(Level.ALL, "Database.Save() Method in Insert.Java, Failed to update database.", ex);
                    MessageBox.ShowMessage(this, ex.toString(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                break;
            }
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION: {
                try
                {
                    Database.RollbackAllSavepoints();
                }
                catch (SQLException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(Insert.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    Log.GetLogger().log(Level.ALL, "Database.Undo() Method in Insert.Java, Failed to update database.", ex);
                    MessageBox.ShowMessage(this, ex.toString(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.dispose(); 
                }
            }
            default: break;
        }
    }
    else
        this.dispose();
}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry, I can't format the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to load 150000 records into memory. I believe you should have a paging and load only a small chunk into memory at a time, like 10 records. If you switch your strategy to use a paging, then your memory problems will be solved.

Comment: No, this is not an answer. My database will probably have 100 rows maximum, but I'm asking if are any ways to free resources? Thanks

Comment: If you put all the fields into the JTable, then you need them into memory. Paging is used precisely to prevent too extensive memory usage. Also, form the point of view of user-experience, it is very bad to scroll a JTable with 150000 records.

Comment: I will do it with paging now and in the future. I believe this is the way. Thanks. But still, when I close (dispose) the JDialog, which clearly dispose jtable and everything else, why it doesn't free up memory resources? Java has another way of freeing memory?

Comment: Java is using a GarbageCollector, you cannot control how memory is freed. If your project does not free the memory for a long time, then you need to dispose your control. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851542/java-dialog-does-not-dispose

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great tool for understanding where your memory is being used, and why: https://eclipse.org/mat/

I'll speculate that: the more times you call tableModel.insertRow, the more memory you'll use.

But run a real memory analysis tool rather than guessing, because often your first guess will be wrong, and the tool will show you the truth.