# latitude, longitude, string value

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to android programming, I have a project and I  want to add Latitude and Longitude in my map, I take those values from web service, and I declare them as a string, but problem is that in my java code it won't take them with method LatLng, I tried to add the codes:

```
} else if (xpp.getName().equals(TAG_LATITUDE)) {
                performance.latitude = valueRead;
            } else if (xpp.getName().equals(TAG_LONGITUDE)) {
                performance.longitude = valueRead;

public String latitude;
public String longitude;


CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 10);
    maps.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

after i try the ways u all told me, i have this problem, the map show nothing, now i add some more codes that i modify after u all told me the ways:

class that i parse xml;

```
public double latitude;
public double longitude;

TAG_LATITUDE = "Latitude", TAG_LONGITUDE = "Longtitude",

} else if (xpp.getName().equals(TAG_LATITUDE)) {
                performance.latitude = Double.parseDouble(valueRead);
            } else if (xpp.getName().equals(TAG_LONGITUDE)) {
                performance.longitude = Double.parseDouble(valueRead);
```

now the class where i work with map;

```
public class KartelaFragment extends Fragment {

private double lat;
private double lng;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View k = inflater.inflate(R.layout.klient_fragment_kartela, container, false);

    mapView = (MapView) k.findViewById(R.id.harta);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    maps = mapView.getMap();
    maps.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    maps.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 10);
    maps.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.title(String.valueOf(klienti));
    marker.snippet(String.valueOf(adresa));
    marker.draggable(true);
    marker.position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    maps.addMarker(marker);
    maps.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    maps.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

lat = (double) k.findViewById(R.id.lati);
    lng = (double) k.findViewById(R.id.longi);




    return k;


void shfaqPerformance(ClientPerformanceList.ClientPerformance performance) {
    lat = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(performance.latitude));
    lng = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(performance.longitude));
```

Comment: Check out my answer. It may helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851542/java-dialog-does-not-dispose).

`LatLng` expects `double` values, but you pass `String`s. You need to convert them to `doubles`, using `Double.parseDouble`.

Answer (score 0):

You will always get the Lat-Long values as of `double` type. So if you want to access it you will have to parse your `String` values into `Double` values as below:

So change your Latitude & Longitude values type to Double and pass it as below:

```
public double latitude;
public double longitude;

CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 10);
    maps.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

If you are getting lat-long values from your webservice in form of `String` then assign it to your variables as below:

```
public double latitude= Double.parseDouble(performance.latitude);
public double longitude= Double.parseDouble(performance.longitude);
```

Comment: well it is very helpful but it gives me some other errors, where should i can talk for it?? do u have any email or smth else where i can talk?

Comment: @DevilVl You can directly post your error in your question only. I will provide you solution.

Comment: well, i have modify the value, i did it double and i have this now: "lat = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(performance.latitude));
        lng = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(performance.longitude));" but now i dont see the map anymore, and latitude and longitude wont show as before :(

Comment: @DevilVl I think your `performance.latitude` values are already in string format ?

Comment: ill send u the full code in parse xml and in java class where i work,

Comment: public double latitude;
public double longitude;

} else if (xpp.getName().equals(TAG_LATITUDE)) {
                    performance.latitude = Double.parseDouble(valueRead);
} else if (xpp.getName().equals(TAG_LONGITUDE)) {
performance.longitude = Double.parseDouble(valueRead);

now the codes where i work:

private double lat;
    private double lng;

lat = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(performance.latitude));
        lng = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(performance.longitude));

Comment: @DevilVl Please post your code in your question. Not in comment.

Answer (score 0):

**try like this**

```
                if (jsonresult == true) {
                    JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        latitude = Jasonobject.getString("latitude");
                        longitude = Jasonobject.getString("longitude");
                        speed=Jasonobject.getString("speed");
                    }
                    double lat=Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                    double lng=Double.parseDouble(longitude);

                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate =CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 10);
                      maps.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```