# JDialog with WindowListener - windowClosing not fired

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, windowlistener

I have a class that extends JDialog that have a window listener:

```
class MyClass extends JDialog {

     public MyClass() {
         setDefaultCloseOperation( JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE );
         addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("closing...");
                    //do something...
                }

            });
     }

}
```

When i click in the X button, nothing happens. And I don't see the print of "closing..."

What I am missing?

Comment: Code looks reasonable, post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)  that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Works for me. See also this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540802/230513).

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

class MyClass extends JDialog {

    public MyClass() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("closing...");
                //do something...
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyClass m = new MyClass();
                m.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for example. I figured out that i'm was calling setVisible before adding the window listener...

Comment: Behold, the power of an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)! I'm pretty sure I've done something similar, too. :-)