# How do I make this java for loop pause for 1/2 a second between each iteration?

Tags: java, swing, loops, timer, delay

```
private class MultipleGensListener implements ActionListener
   {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                game.runSimulationOneGen();
                changeGrid();
            }
        }
   }
```

//this is the loop. The changeGrid method displays a game grid on a GUI but 
// only the 25th iteration is visible on screen. I would like each one to be 
// visible for about a half a second before the loop continues.
// I have seen some questions answered on here that are very close to what I'm asking,
// but I just don't really understand how to apply it to my program..
// thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

If the code performed by the simulation is quick and does not consume too much CPU and time, then consider using a Swing Timer to do your looping and delay. Otherwise, you'll need to use a background thread such as can be done with a SwingWorker object.

For e.g. if using both Swing Timer and SwingWorker:

```
   private class MultipleGensListener implements ActionListener {
      protected static final int MAX_INDEX = 25;

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         int timerDelay = 500; // ms delay
         new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
            int index = 0;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if (index < MAX_INDEX) { // loop only MAX_INDEX times
                  index++;

                  // create the SwingWorker and execute it
                  new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                     @Override
                     protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        game.runSimulationOneGen(); // this is done in background thread.
                        return null;
                     }

                     @Override
                     protected void done() {
                        changeGrid(); // this is called on EDT after background thread done.
                     }
                  }.execute(); // execute the SwingWorker
               } else {
                  ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop(); // stop the timer
               }
            }
         }).start(); // start the Swing timer
      }
   }
```

Comment: @hovercraft,  hmm you are right...didn't even think of that +1

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels nothing else only agreed with that, to avoid to Thread.sleep(int inside ActionListener) +1, uuuupssss where these two posts lost .... :-)

Comment: wow, you guys are quick! I'm new to java so sorry for my ignorance. But can you give me a little more detail or a link to where i can read up on using this? thank you!

Comment: @Bryan: The Swing tutorials are where you need to go. Please check out: [How to use Swing Timers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: cannot find symbol on line with SwingwWorker(). what do I need to import for this?

Comment: @Bryan, my guess is that `changeGrid()` is just some game logic method, but @Hovercraft Full Of Eel assumed that it was a method printing something out to screen (enhance he put it in `done()`, so that the Swing event dispatching thread executes it).  If `changeGrid()` is indeed just a game method, the above code can be simplified, but you still need a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: @Brian, `SwingWorker` is a member class of package `javax.swing`.  You have it no matter what version of Java you are using.

Comment: @toto i've imported javax.swing.*; still getting cannot find symbol. changeGrid() really just changes the color of buttons on my GUI. I think i'm in over my head. haha. Might have to take this one to my teacher. thank you all for being so helpful.

Comment: @Brian, OK so Hover is right, `changeGrid` must be executed in the Swing event thread with `done`.  Swing is annoying... you do have to understand threading to use it.

Comment: @Brian You can use the simpler solution from @ratchet freak if your `runSimulationOneGen` executes quickly.  With his solution your method will be executed in the main Swing thread.  If `runSimulationOneGen` takes too long to execute, your whole application will "freeze" on the user while it executes.  But maybe it's not a big concern for you right now.

Comment: @Brian about not getting symbol: did you spell it right?  in one of your post you spelled it `SwingwWorker()`.  Apparently `SwingWorker` only exists since java 6 (in 2006).

Answer (score 3):

NEVER BLOCK THE GUI EVENT THREAD

you can use a timer for that and have it only fire 25 times

```
final Timer t = new Timer(500,null);
t.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     int i=0;
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         game.runSimulationOneGen();//run 1 iteration per tick
         changeGrid();
         if(i>25){t.stop();}
         i++;
     }
});
t.setRepeats(true);
t.start();
```

btw the reason only the last iteration is shown is that gui updates (redraws) are done in a separate event, but to let another event trigger you need to return from the listener method which you didn't

the Timer I showed is a more elaborate iteration which lets other events run in between iterations allowing the gui to show the changes

Comment: Thanks, this is easier for me to follow than hovercraft's. but i'm getting an error <identifier> expected when the timer "t" is called.

Comment: I've edited the code so it compiles on my machine (that's the problem with code written directly in SO ;) )

Comment: @ratchet freak still not working for me. I don't know why. it's like the compiler doesn't recognize t as a timer, and want's me to redeclare it in every instance. thanks for the help.

Comment: @Brian careful with `java.util.Timer` versus `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: @toto runSimulationOneGen() does execute quickly, im trying to make this work. i don't understand your last comment, be careful of what? anyhow, this just isn't working for me, and I don't understand why not. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Brian If it's quick then this solution is better. If you have `import java.util.*` and `import javax.swing.*`, you'll get some error message if you use `Timer` somewhere in your code.   I'm not sure which message exactly.  To be on the safe side, you can type `final javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(500, null);`.  Otherwise, what error message do you get?

Comment: @toto that what the code in his question did too (sans the 0.5 second delay he wanted)

Comment: @toto that is exactly what I want it to do. run once wait .5 secs then run again a total of 25 times. is this timer java.util.Timer or javax.swing.Timer?  The error i'm getting is "<identifier> expected". In the above code it would be at lines 2, 11 and 12.

Comment: (I deleted my stupid comment...)  ratchet freak uses a Swing `Timer`.  The util `Timer` has nothing to do with `actionPerformed` and `ActionEvent`.

Comment: @bryan to confirm it's a swing timer (`import java.swing.Timer;` to ensure no conflicts occur)

Comment: Again use a **Swing** Timer.  To ratchet, that import should be javax.swing.Timer. but if there's any doubt, don't import at all, but use fully qualified class names when using them.

Comment: I got it working, thanks so much to all you guys! this is a great site. Everyone is so helpful. I really appreciate it. And thanks for being patient with a new guy.

Comment: @toto I compiled it in eclipse, NetBeans just doesn't suit me

Answer (score 1):

check my post that shows both methods [java.swing.Timer#setDelay(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

and

correct usage of [Thread.sleep(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

[java wait cursor display problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051755/java-wait-cursor-display-problem/6060678#6060678)