# What is the correct way to make a thread return a value?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm new to Java threads and after testing to see how they work, I can't figure out how to make them do calculations and return the result the way I want.

For example, in my current program, I want my thread to query a database by calling a method that returns the data in a `Vector` object when I click a `JButton`. Then, with that vector object, I want to add each index (an array) as a row in a `JTable`.

What would be the correct way to accomplish this? I know I could use a setter on my `JTable` in the calling class but I'm sure there has to be a more "correct" way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use a [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). This mechanism is designed for situations where you need to have a long running task run in a background thread and provide updates to the UI either when done, or while processing. Since Swing is single-threaded, this allows the UI to remain *responsive*.

Comment: +1 See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637215/can-a-progress-bar-be-used-in-a-class-outside-main/4637725#4637725).

Answer (score 2):

or [basic workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051755/java-wait-cursor-display-problem/6060678#6060678) by impements [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) where output to the GUI must be wrapped into [invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) more about in [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)