# java how to add WaterMark in JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, paintcomponent

I have a `JTable`, and I am trying to insert an image behind the `JTable` as a Watermark

```
tblMainView= new JTable(dtModel){

        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) 
        {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer( renderer, row, column);
        // We want renderer component to be transparent so background image is visible
        if( c instanceof JComponent )
        ((JComponent)c).setOpaque(true);
        return c;
        }
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon( "images/watermark.png" );

          public void paint( Graphics g )
        {
        // First draw the background image - tiled 
        Dimension d = getSize();
        for( int x = 0; x < d.width; x += image.getIconWidth() )
        for( int y = 0; y < d.height; y += image.getIconHeight() )
        g.drawImage( image.getImage(), x, y, null, null );
        // Now let the regular paint code do it's work
        super.paint(g);
        }


        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
          return false;
        }
        public Class getColumnClass(int col){
            if (col == 0)  
            {  
            return Icon.class;  
            }else if(col==7){
                return String.class;
            }
        else
            return String.class;  

        }   
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            if (autoResizeMode != AUTO_RESIZE_OFF) {
                if (getParent() instanceof JViewport) {
                return (((JViewport)getParent()).getWidth() > getPreferredSize().width);
                }
            } 
            return false;
            }

    };
```

The above is the c
ode of my `JTable`, but the watermark in not visible; let me add that later I place this `JTable` in a `JScrollPane` and `JSplitPane`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solutions, but I don't know which one. :D I think the first approach will have the highest chance of success.

#### First approach

Override your `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    //First super
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

#### Second approach

Set your JTable opaque to false: `table.setOpaque(false);`
Override your `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    //First draw
    g.drawImage(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: simple and short, I think there are "must be" `setOpaque(false)` in both cases for TableRowSelection, +1

Answer (score 3):

there are some mistakes

really not good idea use `paint(Graphics g)` for `Swing JComponents`, `paint()` is for AWT code, for Swing is there `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, usage of `paint(Graphics g)` in Swing would have shows unexpected output to the Swing GUI,

really not good idea `paint(Graphics g)`for AWT code or `paintComponent(Graphics g)` for Swing code inside any of `Renderer`

you have to prepare JTable's BackGroung as is demonstrated here [TableWithGradientPaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051755/java-wait-cursor-display-problem/6060678#6060678)

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `super.paint(g)` before you paint your watermark, the `JTable` is probably painting over your image.