# Java Swing EDT & Concurrency

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread, invokelater

I was just wondering if it is still necessary to ensure synchronicity in an invokeLater() Runnable.

I am encountering deadlock and need to overcome it while maintaining concurrency.

Would this be an example of good code?:

```
private String text;

private void updateText()
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            synchronized(FrameImpl.this)
            {
                someLabel.setText(text);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Sorry for the rather bad example, but we must assume that `text` is being modified by different threads, cannot be injected, and is reliant on a correct value.

Is this the proper solution or will I unintentionally create a deadlock problem by sending synchronized code off into an unknown context..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better solution would be something like this:

```
public class Whatever {
    private String text;
    private final Object TEXT_LOCK = new Object();

    public void setText(final String newText) {
        synchronized (TEXT_LOCK) {
            text = newText;
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                someLabel.setText(newText);
            }
        });
    }

    public String getText() {
        synchronized (TEXT_LOCK) {
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

This will ensure that if two threads try to call `setText` concurrently then they will not clobber each other. The first thread in will set the value of `text` and enqueue a UI update with that value. The second thread will also set the value of `text` and enqueue a second UI update.

The end result is that the UI will eventually show the most recent text value, but the internal `text` variable will **immediately** contain the most recent value.

A couple of notes:

1. Using a seperate lock object (i.e. `TEXT_LOCK`) means you are not vulnerable to code somewhere else locking the  monitor on the `Whatever` instance and inadvertently causing a deadlock. Best to always keep tight control of your lock objects. It's also best to minimize the size of your synchronized blocks.
2. You *could* make the whole `setText` method synchronized, subject to the caveat that it does make you potentially vulnerable to deadlock as above.
3. Reading the value of `text` also needs to be synchronized even though `Strings` are immutable. There are subtleties to the Java memory model that mean you *always* need to synchronize around variables that can be read/written by multiple threads.

Check out Brian Goetz's [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) for a great dive into the tricky parts of concurrency (including the memory model weirdness).

Answer (score -2):

now it would be correct, all output from task must be wrapped ito InvokeLater(), another example for update GUI from BackGround task(s) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051755/java-wait-cursor-display-problem/6060678#6060678)

```
private String text;

private void updateText() {

    synchronized (FrameImpl.this) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                someLabel.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't solve the problem. `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` returns immediately and the `run` method won't be called inside the synchronized scope - only adding the Runnable to the EDT is synchronized and that's not even necessary. With this implementation it's possible for the value of `text` to change between the `invokeLater` call and the actual execution of the `Runnable`.

Comment: I agree with Cameron, I don't think that would do anything productive.

The execution/submission time is irrelevant to me as well--I'm just trying to ensure that the value of `text` is correct and there are no deadlock issues.

Thanks.