# adding data to JTable when working with netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

How can i add data to `JTable` while working with netbeans. Netbeans in it's back code does like this :

```
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null},
            {null, null},
            {null, null},
            {null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Name", "Branch"
        }
    ) {
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false
        };

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    }); // THIS IS THE SNIPPET GENERATED BY NETBEANS
    //( I have already created a table using the drag and drop fetaure of netbeans and this is the back snippet generated)
```

The 2-D object array and String array have local access , so i can't use to fill it when i want to in the middle of the program. *(in some function)*

[image]

like in the above table i will be adding name and branch while in some function.But how can i do this ?

Can anyone please tell a way so that i can add data to JTable ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(value, row, column);
```

Answer (score 3):

`jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(value, row, column);`

Comment: Please, put any comment to your answer. Code-only answers aren't to valuable and aren't welcome here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your question isn't clear for me, but there is basic tutorial about [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), lots of examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Table.htm) or [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/pkg.html), there is example hoe to add value to the [TableCell at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051755/java-wait-cursor-display-problem/6060678#6060678)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from emp"); 
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    int i = 0; 
    if (rs.next()) { 
    String  uname = rs.getString("contact_id"); 
    String  email = rs.getString("first_name");
    String  pass = rs.getString("last_name");
    String cou = rs.getString("phone"); 
    model.addRow(new Object[]{uname, email, pass, cou});
    i++;
}
```