# Set Size of JComboBox PopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, popupmenu

i am programming a custom component which extends a JComboBox. My problem is, the PopupMenu won't actualise its size if i am adding or removing an item. So there are e.g. 2 items in the list, but if there were 4 before i had 2 "empty" items in the PopupMenu as well.

The only workaround i found was to do (in JIntelligentComboBox.java line 213)

`this.setPopupVisible(false);

this.setPopupVisible(true);`

but the result will be a flickering PopupMenu :-(

So what else could i do to refresh/repaint the PopupMenu without flickering?

For testing: [the component](http://nopaste.info/54b42bab5e.html) and a little [test programm](http://nopaste.info/9fe370f64f.html)
To generate my problem you could e.g.:

- type "e"
- press "return"
- type "m"

Thanks in advance

Edit:
My goal is a ComboBox that acts like e.g. the adressbar in Firefox or Chrome, i want to show all items of the PopupMenu that contain the typed chars.

cboxtester.java:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;


public class cboxtester extends JFrame {

    private DefaultComboBoxModel dcm = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new Object[][] {new Object[] {"Mittagessen", "", 0}, 
                                                                                new Object[] {"Essen", "", 0}, 
                                                                                new Object[] {"Frühstück", "", 0}, 
                                                                                new Object[] {"Abendessen", "", 0}});

    private JIntelligentComboBox icb = new JIntelligentComboBox(dcm);

    private cboxtester(){
        this.add(icb, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.add(new JButton("bla"), BorderLayout.EAST);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cboxtester cbt = new cboxtester();
    }

}
```

JIntelligentComboBox.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.ComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.MutableComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxEditor;


public class JIntelligentComboBox extends JComboBox {

    private ArrayList<Object> itemBackup = new ArrayList<Object>();

    /**  Initisiert die JIntelligentComboBox */
    private void init(){

        class searchComboBoxEditor extends BasicComboBoxEditor {
            public searchComboBoxEditor(){
                super();
            }

            @Override
            public void setItem(Object anObject){
                if (anObject == null) {
                    super.setItem(anObject);
                } else {
                    Object[] o = (Object[]) anObject;
                    super.setItem(o[0]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(){
                return new Object[]{super.getItem(), super.getItem(), 0};
            }
        }

        this.setEditor(new searchComboBoxEditor());

        this.setEditable(true);

        class searchRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus){
                if (index == 0) {
                    setText("");
                    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 1));
                    return this;
                }

                this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 17));

                if (index == list.getModel().getSize() - 1) {
                    this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 3, 1, 3));
                } else {
                    this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 3, 0, 3));
                }

                Object[] v = (Object[]) value;
                //System.out.println(v[0]);
                this.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                this.setBackground(Color.white);

                String s = (String) v[0];
                String lowerS = s.toLowerCase();
                String sf = (String) v[1];
                String lowerSf = sf.toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<String> notMatching = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (!sf.equals("")){
                    int fs = -1;
                    int lastFs = 0;
                    while ((fs = lowerS.indexOf((String) lowerSf, (lastFs == 0) ? -1 : lastFs)) > -1) {
                        notMatching.add(s.substring(lastFs, fs));
                        lastFs = fs + sf.length();
                        //System.out.println(fs+sf.length());
                    }
                    notMatching.add(s.substring(lastFs));
                    //System.out.println(notMatching);
                }

                String html = "";

                if (notMatching.size() > 1) {
                    html = notMatching.get(0);
                    int start = html.length();
                    int sfl = sf.length();
                    for (int i = 1; i < notMatching.size(); i++) {
                        String t = notMatching.get(i);
                        html += "<b style=\"color: black;\">" + s.substring(start, start + sfl) + "</b>" + t;
                        start += sfl + t.length();
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(index + html);

                this.setText("<html><head></head><body style=\"color: gray;\">" + html + "</body></head>");
                return this;
            }

        }  

        this.setRenderer(new searchRenderer());

        // leeres Element oben einfügen
        int size = this.getModel().getSize();
        Object[] tmp = new Object[this.getModel().getSize()];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            tmp[i] = this.getModel().getElementAt(i);
            itemBackup.add(tmp[i]);
        }

        this.removeAllItems();

        this.getModel().addElement(new Object[]{"", "", 0});
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            this.getModel().addElement(tmp[i]);
        }

        // keylistener hinzufügen
        this.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                searchAndListEntries(((JTextField)JIntelligentComboBox.this.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText());
                //System.out.println(((JTextField)JIntelligentComboBox.this.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    public JIntelligentComboBox(){
        super();
    }

    public JIntelligentComboBox(MutableComboBoxModel aModel){
        super(aModel);
        init();
    }

    public JIntelligentComboBox(Object[] items){
        super(items);
        init();
    }

    public JIntelligentComboBox(Vector<?> items){
        super(items);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public MutableComboBoxModel getModel(){
        return (MutableComboBoxModel) super.getModel();
    }

    private void searchAndListEntries(Object searchFor){        
        ArrayList<Object> found = new ArrayList<Object>();

        //System.out.println("sf: "+searchFor);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.itemBackup.size(); i++) {
            Object tmp = this.itemBackup.get(i);
            if (tmp == null || searchFor == null) continue;

            Object[] o = (Object[]) tmp;
            String s = (String) o[0];
            if (s.matches("(?i).*" + searchFor + ".*")){
                found.add(new Object[]{((Object[])tmp)[0], searchFor, ((Object[])tmp)[2]});
            }
        }

        this.removeAllItems();          

        this.getModel().addElement(new Object[] {searchFor, searchFor, 0});

        for (int i = 0; i < found.size(); i++) {
            this.getModel().addElement(found.get(i));
        }

        this.setPopupVisible(true);     
    }



}
```

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) code in the forum instead of using links to other websites.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basis of the solution below is to resize the popup every time you invoke the `searchAndListRoutine`. You need to take into account that the popup can be displayed in its own Window when the popup displays outside the bounds of the parent frame or it can be displayed on the layered pane of the parent frame:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;


public class JIntelligentComboBox extends JComboBox {

    private ArrayList<Object> itemBackup = new ArrayList<Object>();

    /**  Initisiert die JIntelligentComboBox */
    private void init(){

        class searchComboBoxEditor extends BasicComboBoxEditor {
            public searchComboBoxEditor(){
                super();
            }

            @Override
            public void setItem(Object anObject){
                if (anObject == null) {
                    super.setItem(anObject);
                } else {
                    Object[] o = (Object[]) anObject;
                    super.setItem(o[0]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(){
                return new Object[]{super.getItem(), super.getItem(), 0};
            }
        }

        this.setEditor(new searchComboBoxEditor()); 

        this.setEditable(true); 

        class searchRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer { 

            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus){
                if (index == 0) { 
                    setText(""); 
                    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 1)); 
                    return this; 
                } 

                this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 17)); 

                if (index == list.getModel().getSize() - 1) { 
                    this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 3, 1, 3)); 
                } else { 
                    this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 3, 0, 3)); 
                }

                Object[] v = (Object[]) value; 
                //System.out.println(v[0]);
                this.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                this.setBackground(Color.white);

                String s = (String) v[0];
                String lowerS = s.toLowerCase();
                String sf = (String) v[1];
                String lowerSf = sf.toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<String> notMatching = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (!sf.equals("")){
                    int fs = -1;
                    int lastFs = 0;
                    while ((fs = lowerS.indexOf((String) lowerSf, (lastFs == 0) ? -1 : lastFs)) > -1) {
                        notMatching.add(s.substring(lastFs, fs));
                        lastFs = fs + sf.length();
                        //System.out.println(fs+sf.length());
                    }
                    notMatching.add(s.substring(lastFs));
                    //System.out.println(notMatching);
                }

                String html = "";

                if (notMatching.size() > 1) {
                    html = notMatching.get(0);
                    int start = html.length();
                    int sfl = sf.length();
                    for (int i = 1; i < notMatching.size(); i++) {
                        String t = notMatching.get(i);
                        html += "<b style=\"color: black;\">" + s.substring(start, start + sfl) + "</b>" + t;
                        start += sfl + t.length();
                    }
                }

                this.setText("<html><head></head><body style=\"color: gray;\">" + html + "</body></head>");
                return this;
            }

        }

        this.setRenderer(new searchRenderer());

        //
        int size = this.getModel().getSize();
        Object[] tmp = new Object[this.getModel().getSize()];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            tmp[i] = this.getModel().getElementAt(i);
            itemBackup.add(tmp[i]);
        }

        this.removeAllItems();

        this.getModel().addElement(new Object[]{"", "", 0});
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            this.getModel().addElement(tmp[i]);
        }

        //
        this.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() { 

            @Override 
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            } 

            @Override 
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                searchAndListEntries(((JTextField)JIntelligentComboBox.this.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText()); 
                //System.out.println(((JTextField)JIntelligentComboBox.this.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText()); 
            } 

            @Override 
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }
        });
    }

    public JIntelligentComboBox(){ 
        super(); 
    } 

    public JIntelligentComboBox(MutableComboBoxModel aModel){
        super(aModel); 
        init(); 
    } 

    public JIntelligentComboBox(Object[] items){
        super(items);
        init();
    }

    public JIntelligentComboBox(Vector<?> items){
        super(items);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public MutableComboBoxModel getModel(){
        return (MutableComboBoxModel) super.getModel();
    }

    private void searchAndListEntries(Object searchFor){
        ArrayList<Object> found = new ArrayList<Object>();

        //System.out.println("sf: "+searchFor);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.itemBackup.size(); i++) {
            Object tmp = this.itemBackup.get(i);
            if (tmp == null || searchFor == null) continue;

            Object[] o = (Object[]) tmp;
            String s = (String) o[0];
            if (s.matches("(?i).*" + searchFor + ".*")){
                found.add(new Object[]{((Object[])tmp)[0], searchFor, ((Object[])tmp)[2]});
            }
        }

        this.removeAllItems();

        this.getModel().addElement(new Object[] {searchFor, searchFor, 0});

        for (int i = 0; i < found.size(); i++) {
            this.getModel().addElement(found.get(i));
        }

        //this.setPopupVisible(true);
        int size = this.getModel().getSize() - 1;

        System.out.println("Elements: " + size);

        if (size == 0)
        {
            this.setPopupVisible( false );
            return;
        }

        this.setPopupVisible(true);

        BasicComboPopup popup =
            (BasicComboPopup)this.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
        Window popupWindow = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(popup);
        Window comboWindow = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);

        if (comboWindow.equals(popupWindow))
        {
            Component c = popup.getParent();
            Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
            c.setSize(d);
        }
        else
        {
            popupWindow.pack();
        }
    }
}
```

The one issue is that when the combo box field is empty the model contains 4 entries. I would guess that is a problem with your matching logic.

Comment: +1 I see a similar result on `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (couldn't resist :-)

Comment: That's it!! Thank you very much :-) my plan was also to access the PopupMenu, but i didn't know how to do

@kleopatra do you have a link to the naming conventions? i am usually programming in c++ or delphi/pascal and i am relatively new to java, that might cause some issues ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I have revised your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) below, and I noticed a few things:

1. The anomaly you observe is not apparent when using [`apple.laf.AquaComboBoxUI`](http://www.duncanjauncey.com/java/ui/uimanager/UIDefaults_Java1.5.0_16_Mac_OS_X_10.4.11_Mac_OS_X.html). In particular, entering and deleting text grows and shrinks the list as expected. You might try the revised code on your platform.
2. I switched from `KeyListener` to `KeyAdapter` for expedience, but that's not a solution. You should probably use a `DocumentListener`. It can't be mutated while in use, as you are doing now, so I didn't pursue this further.
3. Always build the GUI on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
4. Hard-coded dimensions and novel fonts rarely look right on other look & feel implementations. I simply removed yours to get the appearance shown.
5. Your constructor modifies the model after constructing the parent, so the result depends on the order of instantiation. A separate model might be easier to manage.

Update: Added code to verify @camickr's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604005/set-size-of-jcombobox-popupmenu/7605995#7605995).

[image: Combo image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.MutableComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup;

public class CBoxTest extends JFrame {

    private CBoxTest() {
        DefaultComboBoxModel dcm = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (char i = 'a'; i < 'm'; i++) {
            s.append(i);
            dcm.addElement(new Object[]{s.toString(), "", 0});
        }
        JIntelligentComboBox icb = new JIntelligentComboBox(dcm);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(icb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(new JButton("Button"), BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CBoxTest cbt = new CBoxTest();
            }
        });
    }

    class JIntelligentComboBox extends JComboBox {

        private List<Object> itemBackup = new ArrayList<Object>();

        public JIntelligentComboBox(MutableComboBoxModel aModel) {
            super(aModel);
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            this.setRenderer(new searchRenderer());
            this.setEditor(new searchComboBoxEditor());
            this.setEditable(true);
            int size = this.getModel().getSize();
            Object[] tmp = new Object[this.getModel().getSize()];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                tmp[i] = this.getModel().getElementAt(i);
                itemBackup.add(tmp[i]);
            }
            this.removeAllItems();
            this.getModel().addElement(new Object[]{"", "", 0});
            for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                this.getModel().addElement(tmp[i]);
            }
            final JTextField jtf = (JTextField) this.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
            jtf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    searchAndListEntries(jtf.getText());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public MutableComboBoxModel getModel() {
            return (MutableComboBoxModel) super.getModel();
        }

        private void searchAndListEntries(Object searchFor) {
            List<Object> found = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.itemBackup.size(); i++) {
                Object tmp = this.itemBackup.get(i);
                if (tmp == null || searchFor == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                Object[] o = (Object[]) tmp;
                String s = (String) o[0];
                if (s.matches("(?i).*" + searchFor + ".*")) {
                    found.add(new Object[]{
                            ((Object[]) tmp)[0], searchFor, ((Object[]) tmp)[2]
                        });
                }
            }
            this.removeAllItems();
            this.getModel().addElement(new Object[]{searchFor, searchFor, 0});
            for (int i = 0; i < found.size(); i++) {
                this.getModel().addElement(found.get(i));
            }
            this.setPopupVisible(true);
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605995
            BasicComboPopup popup =
                (BasicComboPopup) this.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
            Window popupWindow = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(popup);
            Window comboWindow = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);

            if (comboWindow.equals(popupWindow)) {
                Component c = popup.getParent();
                Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                c.setSize(d);
            } else {
                popupWindow.pack();
            }
        }

        class searchRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    setText("");
                    return this;
                }
                Object[] v = (Object[]) value;
                String s = (String) v[0];
                String lowerS = s.toLowerCase();
                String sf = (String) v[1];
                String lowerSf = sf.toLowerCase();
                List<String> notMatching = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (!sf.equals("")) {
                    int fs = -1;
                    int lastFs = 0;
                    while ((fs = lowerS.indexOf(lowerSf, (lastFs == 0) ? -1 : lastFs)) > -1) {
                        notMatching.add(s.substring(lastFs, fs));
                        lastFs = fs + sf.length();
                    }
                    notMatching.add(s.substring(lastFs));
                }
                String html = "";
                if (notMatching.size() > 1) {
                    html = notMatching.get(0);
                    int start = html.length();
                    int sfl = sf.length();
                    for (int i = 1; i < notMatching.size(); i++) {
                        String t = notMatching.get(i);
                        html += "<b style=\"color: black;\">"
                            + s.substring(start, start + sfl) + "</b>" + t;
                        start += sfl + t.length();
                    }
                }
                this.setText("<html><head></head><body style=\"color: gray;\">"
                    + html + "</body></head>");
                return this;
            }
        }

        class searchComboBoxEditor extends BasicComboBoxEditor {

            public searchComboBoxEditor() {
                super();
            }

            @Override
            public void setItem(Object anObject) {
                if (anObject == null) {
                    super.setItem(anObject);
                } else {
                    Object[] o = (Object[]) anObject;
                    super.setItem(o[0]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem() {
                return new Object[]{super.getItem(), super.getItem(), 0};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

not tested your code,

please advice for content of Renderer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573508/changing-cursor-when-rendering-a-jlist/7573730#7573730) and for AutoComplete JComboBox [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist/7255918#7255918)

Comment: well, i checked them out both, but they are not helpfull the "Renderer" might be a upcoming problem, if i test my box with more entries ;-) and the other one does not use the PopupMenu permanently... i try to get an combobox like the adressbar in firefox or chrome (without the web-search option ;-) )

Comment: +1 Here's another `JComboBox` [variation](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/11/06/autocomplete-jcombobox/).

Comment: that variation is very nice, but not realy what i need, because this version doesn't seems to support editable comboboxes, well that's a way to avoid my problem with the popup refresh, but not what i want. furthermore it dose not support to list "football" if you type "ball". but thanks anyway... i am gonna go to bed now, pleas don't expect an answer from me within the next ours ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem using Vector array in ComboboxModel that extends AbstractListModel &
implements MutableComboBoxModel. Solved using setMaximumRowCount:

1. iterate over database values and save them into
   public ArrayList listInCombobox = new ArrayList();
2. myComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(listInCombobox.size());
3. do the above inside myComboBox MouseListener (mousePressed).

Answer (score -3):

Did you tried this?

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#updateUI()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#updateUI%28%29)

Comment: yes, but the result is, that the ComboBox is losing its focus and the PopupMenu collapses -.-

Comment: -1 any suggestion to use the updateUI() method is almost certainly wrong. The LAF has NOT changed.