# Java Swing setEditable(boolean) not working in JComboBox with custom renderer

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, packaging, renderer

I have a `JComboBox` of type `myclass`. I use `CustomListRender` to display one of the attributes of `myclass`, and it works fine.

Then I set `myCombobox.setEditable(true)`. `JComboBox` becomes editable, but by default text is set to somthing like this in `combobox`:

```
 com.mypackagename.myclass
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you'll also want to create and use a custom ComboBoxEditor.

Comment: you may use **setSelectedIndex(int anIndex)**  or **setSelectedItem(Object anObject)** to initialize your ComboBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [*How to Use Combo Boxes: Providing a Custom Renderer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer),

> The default renderer knows how to render strings and icons. If you put other objects in a combo box, the default renderer calls the `toString` method to provide a string to display.

Unless overridden, you're probably seeing the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) implementation inherited from `Object`. At a minimum, you'll need to override `MyClass#toString()` or <strike>update your renderer</strike> supply a [custom editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) accordingly; there's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605780/230513). Most would prefer the latter; your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) showing your custom renderer would make it easier to suggest alternatives.

Comment: `MyClass` used to conform to Java class naming convention.

Comment: As far as I understand the question, he already has a custom renderer. What he needs is a custom editor as well, to avoid the `toString` call of the standard editor. And I am not a big fan of overriding the `toString` for UI purposes

Comment: @Robin: Good point about the editor; updated. I'd welcome a more relevant example than the one I cited. I'm more sanguine about overriding `toString()`, say in `enum`. I focused on that to explain the (presumed) result mentioned in the question. Can you elaborate on the pitfalls?

Comment: Not a real pitfall, except that even in production code I dare changing the `toString` method regularly to provide better information (for example for printing more information in a logger). A hidden dependency on that method by using a default renderer/editor iso a custom one could break a UI in that case. And my IDE would never discover that the `toString` was used in the renderer