# Java:Swing JComboBox - is it possible to hide items ?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a jcombobox with multiple entries. I want to filter the list as the user starts typing. How is it possible to hide entries in the jcombobox upon keyboard event?

Answer (score 2):

Use regex to filter List of items and just update JCombobox with new `ComboBoxModel`.

Something like:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel comboModel = ((DefaultComboBoxModel)yourComboBox.getModel());

....

// invoke regex on yourArray 

comboModel.removeAllElements();

for(int i = 0; i<yourArray.length; i++) {
  comboModel.addElement(yourArray[i]);  
}
```

**[EDIT]**

if you don't want to use two lists: one for actual data, two - for filtered data,

write custom ComboBoxModel where you can implement "hide" ability.

Comment: If i use a regular expression, i would have to store the values in another array ... which would imply that i would duplicate data? or am i missing something

Comment: if you want to "hide", yes use 2 arrays no way. I don't see other way

Comment: because `removeAllItems` refers to `JCombobox` and here I use `DefaultComboBoxModel`

Comment: +1 for dynamically updating the model; for reference, a related example is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7605780/230513).