# Thread out of the EDT

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread, swingutilities

Hi i'd like to do a task out of the EDT :

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    fBPC.repaint();
                    System.out.println("toto");
                    if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()){
                        System.out.println("titi");
                    }
                }
            }).run();
```

It display that:

toto

titi

Am i not supposed to get only : "toto" because i created a new Thread ?

If not please explain me how to make things in a thread ou of the EDT.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: [for example Runnable#Thread and invokeLater()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6060678/714968), more in Oracle tutorial Concurency in Swing. or to use SwingWorker, there are implemented methods in API that notify EDT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Thread.start()` instead of `Thread.run()`.