# Stop JScrollPane from redraw JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jscrollpane, redraw

I have a JPanel with a JScrollPane sorounding it, the problem is that when i use the JScrollPane the JPanels redraw methode get called. I want to disable that because my JPanel redraw by its self at the right time.

I want it so it just updateds the getClipBounds() for the paint methode but withoud calling the paint methode.

Comment: This might help, im not sure, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249278/how-to-disable-the-default-painting-behaviour-of-wheel-scroll-event-on-jscrollpa

Comment: I found that too, but it dosent help because that methods dont disable it.

Comment: Not how the API works - Instead, paint the contents of your panel to a `BufferedImage` when it changes and simply paint that when `paintComponent` get's called

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that - since the viewport displays different parts of the contained JPanel, depending on the position of the scrollbar, the areas that have to be repainted might in fact be newly revealed and might not have been painted before.

Since `JScrollPane` doesn't know how the contained `Component` is implemented and whether it repaints its entire area or only the area that needs repainting, it forces the contained `Component` to redraw itself upon scrolling.

However, you can instead render the content you want to show to a bitmap, and then paint the bitmap in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method. Thus, you effectively buffer your painted content and can initiate an update to the buffered bitmap whenever it suits you.

In order to paint onto a bitmap, you can do this:

```
BufferedImage buffer; // this is an instance variable

private void updateBuffer(){
   // Assuming this happens in a subclass of JPanel, where you can access
   // getWidth() and getHeight()
   buffer=new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   Graphics g=buffer.getGraphics();
   // Draw into the graphic context g...
   g.dispose();
}
```

Then, in your JPanel, you override the paintComponent method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
}
```

Comment: You should pass `this` as the `ImageObserver` parameter for `drawImage` - purely as convention